# how to display the selected image when the upload image button is clicked in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def mfileopen():
    file1=fd.askopenfile()

button3 = Button(root, text = "Upload Image", command=mfileopen, bg='white', fg ='black', font=('comicsans', 13))
button3.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

I created the **Upload Button** using **Python Tkinter** which shows what image would you like to upload. Now, how do I display the selected image in a different window where I can edit the uploaded image?

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet, and i am still searching for a tutorial for that but i do not see one..

Comment: Okay so what you can do is: 

**1.** take the image location,

**2.** then create a new top-level(tkinter window),

**3.** then open the image from image location on a canvas on the top-level.

Comment: i have another problem about image location, the error always indicate "No such file or directory" something

Comment: update your code with current state.

Comment: okay! i will try that later. i hope it works thanks